# QT -> timer loop, would this cause a stack overflow

Tags: c++, qt, stack-overflow

Would the following create a stack overflow?

```
// reference elsewhere
this->update();


void devices::Sprinkler::update(){
    if(this->_state == devices::Sprinkler::State::ON) {
        ...
        QTimer::singleShot(this->_updateFrequency, this, SLOT(update()));
    }
}
```

I know that if it were

```
update() {
    update(); // stack overflow 
}
```

but I don't fullly understand how the former would behave.

Comment: Did you try it? Did you read the [documentation of Qt](https://doc.qt.io/)? Qt is open source, did you study its [source code repository](https://github.com/qt) ? I would bet that your first code snippet could work, but you don't provide any  [mre]. Consider compiling your code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) then using [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to understand its behavior

Comment: And since Qt is open source, you could compile it (on Linux) with [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug information, using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as `g++ -Wall -g`. Read about [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). Qt is big, compiling it from source code may take several hours.

Comment: I guess this was more of a passing question that I do not have the time to spent hours researching into. I've read parts of the QT documentation but still struggle to figure out exactly how the event loop works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not cause a stack overflow, because the call is not recursive. `QTimer::singleShot()` schedules a call for *execution at a later time*, allowing `update()` to exit and clean up its stack frame before it is called again, thus reusing stack space.